# Rename default "Example" directory in pod init

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I am following this tutorial in creating a private pod: https://medium.com/practical-code-labs/how-to-create-private-cocoapods-in-swift-3cc199976a18 . When I run the following command, I can see an "Example" directory:

```
pod lib create HandyExtensions
```

"Example" is only useful to me the first time I run the command. I'd like to change it to something more meaningful, like "Workspace". How can I rename this folder to ensure it plays well with Xcode?

(I've tried many things ranging from renaming to cleaning workspaces. However, I always come back to the error of : No such module : when I try to test my private pod. A step by step solution, or even a command would help me resolve this annoyance )

Comment: It seems like you'd need to use a custom template and not the default one: https://github.com/CocoaPods/pod-template where there is the "Example": https://github.com/CocoaPods/pod-template/tree/master/templates using `--template-url=UR`.

Answer (score 0):

`pod lib create` is really only intended for initial creation.

`pod gen` is more useful for building workspaces for testing already existing pods. See https://github.com/square/cocoapods-generate for usage instructions.